# Why does Django create migrations in the parent model's app when they are inherited?

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-apps

I have the following setup, an external dependency `dep` is installed and being used in my Django project and I'm extending one of it's models in my own apps, like the following:

```py
from dep.models import ParentModel

class MyModel(ParentModel):
    # fields
```

Both mine and the dependency models are *not* abstract and by running `makemigrations` a new migration is created into the `dep` app, following it's current migration tree.

The problem is that I expect to have a new migration in **my** own app as it doesn't make sense to mess with the dependency's migration structure as it's gonna create all sorts of problems whenever it's updated.

Is there a way to go around this?

I've tried moving the migrations manually to my app but when I run `makemigrations` again, it gets deleted and created again the same way as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out and the point is that the inherited model's `Meta` class has the `app_label` explicitly set which is also inherited by my model, forcing it to be a migration on the same app.

To fix it, I just had to set the same attributes in my model and now the migration is created as I expected.

Here's the example of the base model and mine:

```py
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = "dep"


class MyModel(ParentModel):
    class Meta:
        app_label = "my_app"
```